# Nullpointexception thrown at DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullpointerexception

I am getting a Nullpoint exception when the page loads. How can i prevent it ?

```
protected override void InitializeCulture() 
{ 
    base.InitializeCulture();
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value != null) // NULL POINT EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
    {
       //
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that the `InitializeCulture` runs too early in the ASP.NET execution lifecycle where controls haven't been loaded values yet.

Answer (score 0):

You prevent the NullReferenceException by either making sure that DropDownList1 and SelectedItem are both not null, or moving the code to a point where they are not null, or changing the if-statement to check if DropDownList1 or SelectItem is null before checking DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.

Answer (score 0):

`InitializeCulture` is generally called too early in the page life cycle (before view-state etc are loaded so it might be problematic to refer controls). I am assuming probably want to set the current culture using value selected in drop-dwon list. For that, you should sniff the `Request.Form` rather than using the control reference. For example,

```
protected override void InitializeCulture() 
{ 
    base.InitializeCulture();
    var selectedCulture = Request.Form["DowndownListName"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedCulture))
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

*DowndownListName* should be the `UniqueID` of the server side control (and name attribute of rendered select element in rendered html source). I will suggest to use html control (instead of server control) to have a static name that can be hard-coded in the source.